# Pro*C: inserting a date

Tags: c, oracle

I have a piece of code such as:

```
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
    typedef struct {
        char date_field[26 + 1];
        // other fields
    } proc_row;
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

void insert()
{
    EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
        proc_row row;
    EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

    std::strcpy(row.date_field, "31/07/23");

    EXEC SQL
    INSERT INTO some_table (
        SOME_DATE, ...
    ) VALUES (:row);

    check_ok(); // Check if there's any error and print it.
}
```

But `check_ok` prints that my format is wrong (ORA-01843: not a valid month). Yes, I know that I could set the date format, but it could affect other functions on the same session, etc. Of course, I coul replace `VALUES (:row)`, by a comma-separated list of fields so I can use the `TO_DATE` function to specify the format of my input date.

But I want to use the struct for escalability (imagine a pointer to an array of structs using the `EXEC SQL FOR :size` syntax).

How many ways do I have to insert dates in a safe manner without having to expand the contents of the struct into a list of fields on the `VALUES` line?

- Any struct that Pro*C understands, like VARCHAR2 but for dates (not datetimes)?
- If I replace `date_field` by `time_t` or an unsigned, would Pro*C understand I'm using a Unix timestamp? (and so format-related issues are gone)

**NOTE:** I know I can also set the variable `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` (I still prefer a non-string based solution) for my current session, but I'm not sure about some things:

- I'm unsure about how contexts exactly work in Pro*C. If I'm not wrong, sessions = sql_context. So if I have, let's say, a pool of sql_context, modifying it would imply some else using the same context later on would be affected by the change.
- That would imply I should restore `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` to its original value after the insert, which means I have to do two extra executions, which means two more extra network communications, which means an artificial increase on performance. Am I right?